# Meteor Collection naming convention

Tags: meteor

I have inherited a naming convention form a tutorial but am not sure that it is the best:

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts", {.......
```

Note the case on the naming, now this gets quite confusing when working between code/the mongo console/minimongo console - are there any reasons not to use the same name:

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("Posts", {.......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with your own convention as long as you abide by a [few restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions) that are native to mongodb.

Basically, stick with letters and numbers and you're all good.

Using the same name, though, can get confusing very quickly. You'll hit log messages, error messages etc in very different places and you'll soon find yourself wondering which `Posts` the message is referring to.

I, personally, like it when the name is verbose. For example, I'd go even further to do:

```
PostsCollection = new Meteor.Collection("postsdb", {.......);
```

Also, mongodb database (collection) names being case sensitive, it is always a safeguard measue to keep your db names all lowercase to avoid any potential portability issues that you may get between dumps and restores or direct porting between *nix and windows machines.

Answer (score 2):

The Meteor recommendation [meteor docs](https://guide.meteor.com/code-style.html#collections) is to use:

*CamelCaseCollectionName* = new Mongo.Collection(*'lowercasecollectionname'*)

```
    Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts', {...});
```

In this way, there is no confusion, when you received a message, with **lowercase** is a mongo side, if is an **uppercase** will be Meteor Collection's side.

As well, keep names in plural  ;-)